# MVC: 2D array can only be received in controller as 1D

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have a 2D array created using JS in my view like so:

```
var tableValueList = [];
for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
    var rowValueList = [];
    for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
        var value = "value"
        rowValueList.push(value);
    }
    tableValueList.push(rowValueList);
}
```

and I use ajax to pass it back to my controller, making sure that I set `traditional` to `true`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("SaveChanges")",
    traditional: true,
    data: { "tableValueList": tableValueList},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        *success stuff*
    }
});
```

However, when I try to specify the parameter in my controller, I only successfully get the passed array if I set it as `IEnumerable`, `string[]`, or any 1D array. But each string element of the array is multiple values in string form separated by commas: `"Value 1, Value 2, Value 3"`.

When I try to specify the parameter as a 2D array, such as `string[,]`, `string[][]` or `List<List<String>>`, I get null as the parameter. When I use `string[,]`, I get the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

```
public JsonResult SaveStationConfigChanges(string[] tableValueList)
{
    *method stuff*
}
```

I've tried testing to see if my array really is 2D by using commands like `alert(tableValueList[1][1])` and setting breakpoints, and verified that it is indeed a 2D array in my view.

How can I pass the 2D array successfully? Thank you!

Worst case scenario I just leave it as is, and do some manipulation on my part to extract the data I need from the 1D array.

Update: I proceeded with just using `string.Split()` to solve the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using model/viewmodel to bind?

Comment: @sairfan yeppers :P

Comment: Looking at that, that's not a 2d array is it, it is an array of string arrays.  Your parameter type should be IEnumerable<string[]>

Comment: @Slicksim I tried using IEnumerable<string[]> and IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>. While it doesn't give me null, it gives me an array with no values in it. Saying the Value is Count=0.